# Is there a way to reload cellEditorParams in ag-grid editable cell of type agSelectCellEditor?

Tags: ag-grid

I am using agSelectCellEditor to show a dropdown in a particular column cells. This is the column definition:

```
{
    headerName: 'Service', field: 'ServiceId', width: 180, suppressMenu: true, lockPosition: true, type: 'numberColumn',
    cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
    cellEditorParams: {
        values: extractValues($scope.Services)
    },
    valueFormatter: function (params) {
        if (!params.node || params.node.data.Id === 0) {
            return lookupValue($scope.Services, params.value);
        }
        else {
            return params.node.data.ServiceName;
        }
    },
    valueParser: function (params) {
        return lookupKey($scope.Services, params.newValue);
    },
    editable: function (params) {
        return params.node.data.UIRecordCategory === "Yes" && params.node.data.Id === 0;
    }
}
```

above code works fine when user lands on the page first time. There is another even outside of the grid which pulls data from server. On the success of that event, values in the editable cell dropdown should get reloaded. But thats not happening. It continues to show old values.

Is there any way I can reload `cellEditorparams` on an event?